# Quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] /\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am learning rings right now in groups theory course.
I am asked to describe exactly what elements the quotient ring  $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] /\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$ contains, where $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+1$.

I have not fully understood the quotient ring definition. could you guys help me understand what elements this ring contains and why?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It is represented by $0, 1, 2, i, i+1, i+2, 2i, 2i+1, $ and $2i+2$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you. I cant understand why unfortunately..

Comment: ofirsas, the elements in the quotient ring can be represented by $\{a + bx: a, b \in\{0, 1, -1\}\}$. This is explained in the duplicate. You can "identify" these nine elements with the ones above.